# Incompleteness in reverse

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Take a consistent formal system $F$ within which a certain amount of elementary arithmetic can be carried out.

Now out of the statements in $F$ there are those that can be proven true or false, and there are necessarily, due to the first incompleteness theorem, those that can’t be proven true or false within $F$.

Let’s take an arbitrary such statement $a$.

What we can do from there on is the following: we can find an undecideable statement $g$ in $F$ by following Gödel’s constructive argument, and add it to the system $F$ as a new axiom arriving at a more powerful system $G$. Then find the statement $h$ in $G$ and so on.

Of course each of the systems we construct will be incomplete.

However, here comes my question. Is it always the case that $a$ (an arbitrary statement that we fixed in $F$) can be proven true after adding a finite amount of new axioms?

Comment: Add $a$ as an axiom, now you can prove $a.$

Comment: @MichaelBarz oh sure, but what if we aren’t certain in the validity of $a$? We can add $g$ because it is known to be true (otherwise $F$ is inconsistent). In my question, I assume that we always add the Gödel’s statement until we can reach a system powerful enough to prove an unrelated statement $a$. My question is — if $a$ is true after all, will we always reach a proof of it, and whether this is even known

Comment: By Godel's completeness theorem, an undecidable statement $a$ exists precisely because it is true in some models and false in other models. It is somewhat meaningless to ask about the validity of $a$--it depends on the model. Both $a$ and "not $a$" are consistent additions to your theory.

Comment: Perhaps what you're asking is this:  Start with $F$, add its Godel sentence, then add the Godel sentence of that theory, and so on.  After infinitely many steps, will you have a complete theory?  The answer is no: the incompleteness theorem can be applied to the theory you get after infinitely many steps.

Comment: @DanVelleman that’s not what I am asking. Let’s say a and not a are both undecideable and I don’t know which is true and which is false, and am unwilling to accept an answer until I have a proof (not necessarily in $F$). Let’s also say $a$ is actually true, it’s just I don’t know about this. If I start adding the statement that Gödel constructs in his proof (not that it is not $a$ but a different statement) repeatedly, I am asking whether I will eventually have a system strong enough to prove $a$ or whether this process can go on forever

Comment: @DanVelleman in the version of the question that you have in your comment, one wonders about completeness, which is existence of proof of any statement or it’s negation in the system. I am asking about extstence of proof of any statement that also exists in the original system.

Comment: @Prof. Legolasov Doesn't my comment answer your question?  After infinitely many steps, the theory is still incomplete, so there is some statement that is neither provable nor disprovable.  Let $b$ be such a statement.  Now let $a$ be either $b$ or $\neg b$, whichever is true.  Then $a$ is a true statement that was not provable in $F$ and that does not become provable after any finite number of steps of adding Godel sentences.

Comment: @DanVelleman you are right. My confusion stemmed from that I imagined that adding a new axiom somehow extends the set of possible sentences, and the new incompeteness theorem applies to the new set but not the old one. I don't understand now why I would think that. If you promote your comment to an answer I will upvote and accept. Thank you

Comment: @DanVelleman also an explanation (even if a quick draft of one) of why after infinity steps the incompleteness theorem is still applicable (and what does "after infinity steps" even mean in this context) would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @MichaelBarz - I think your characterization is incorrect.  It isn't that it may or may not be true, but that it *is* either true or false, but we can't deduce it based on the axioms.

The best practical example for thinking about Godel Incompleteness is the halting problem in Turing machines.  Whether or not a program will halt is undecidable, but it *will* do one or the other.  That is the truth/falsity of halting is within the system even if it is outside of the ability to demonstrate it within the system.

Comment: @johnnyb By Godel's completeness theorem, the only way we are unable to prove something in a first order system is if there are models of that system where it is true, and models where it is false. I stand by what I said, and I think you are conflating decidability with provability.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Alan Turing's PhD thesis answers this question: https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~acm/turing-phd.pdf . I'm still working through it myself, so can't say much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g_1$ be the Godel sentence of $F$, and let $F_1 = F + g_1$.  In other words, $F_1$ is the formal system that is the same as $F$, except that $g_1$ is added as an additional axiom.  Now let $g_2$ be the Godel sentence of $F_1$, and let $F_2 = F_1 + g_2$.  In general, we let $F_{n+1} = F_n + g_{n+1}$, where $g_{n+1}$ is the Godel sentence of $F_n$.  Now let $F_\omega$ be the formal system in which all of the statements $g_n$ are added to $F$ as additional axioms.  Then the incompleteness theorem can be applied to $F_\omega$ as well.  Now let $a$ be the Godel sentence of $F_\omega$.  Then $a$ is true but not provable in $F_\omega$, and therefore it is not provable in any $F_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Gödel sentences are by construction $\Pi^0_1$ statements, that is, they have the form "for all $n$ ...", where ... is a recursive statement (think "a statement that a computer can decide"). For instance, the typical Gödel sentence for a system $T$ coming from the second incompleteness theorem says that "for all $n$ that code a proof in $T$, $n$ is not coding a proof of a contradiction", and a similar observation holds for the sentence from the first incompleteness theorem.

Under mild assumptions on $T$ (say, the assumptions on the incompleteness theorem and that $T$ is true in the standard model of arithmetic), you could add to it all true $\Pi^0_1$ statements, many of which are not provable in $T$ and many of which are not Gödel sentences. The result is a theory to which the incompleteness theorem no longer applies (it is not recursive), and yet it is still far from complete and there are $\Pi^0_2$ statements that are not provable in it (assertions that certain recursive functions are total). There are similar results if you proceed to add all true $\Pi^0_2$ statements to this theory and so on.

The assumption that $T$ is true is perhaps too strong. We can say something very general even without this requirement: the other answer indicated that if we start with $T_0=T$ and recursively form $T_{n+1}$ by adding to $T_n$ its Gödel sentence, then the incompleteness theorem still applies to the union of the $T_n$. There is a general fact here: If $\{T_k: k\in\mathbb N\}$ is a recursively enumerable family of theories (meaning, there is an algorithm that generates all pairs $(\phi,n)$ such that $\phi$ is a sentence and $\phi\in T_n$), there is a $\Pi^0_1$ sentence which is
simultaneously undecidable in all the theories $T_k$.

There are some excellent references for these and many additional results. In particular, I recommend "Aspects of incompleteness" by P. Lindström and "Metamathematics of first-order arithmetic" by P. Hájek and P. Pudlák.